# jQuery show options when click on an input field is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a snippet that asks user to input some value in input field. These values are predefined. I can use dropdown instead of it. But using dropdown will increase the work load. The scenario is this whenever user want to write some text in input field, some options will be shown with each input field, user will select a value and the selected value will be populated in that field. I have done it but as I select a value it updates tha same value in all (previously/next) input fields.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Select</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {

    $(".font-select option").filter(function() {

        var current_field = $(this);

        return $(current_field).val() == $(".product_addon_option_label").val();

    }).attr('selected', true);

    $(".font-select").live("change", function() {

        $(".product_addon_option_label").val($(current_field).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="300">
  <tbody class="ui-sortable" style="">
    <tr class="" style="">
      <td><input class="product_addon_option_label" name="product_addon_option_label" value="Arial" placeholder="Label" type="text">
        <select class="font-select">
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two" selected="selected">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" style="">
      <td><input class="product_addon_option_label" name="product_addon_option_label" value="Thohm" placeholder="Label" type="text">
        <select class="font-select">
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two" selected="selected">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think jQuery Autocomplete will be helpful for you

Comment: The live() function is depreciated. Better use on()

Comment: @Gerard - Its deprecated 1.7 onwards, OP is using 1.3.0

Comment: I have used 'on' instead of 'live' but still no success.

Comment: The `current_field` variable inside the `live` change function is not declared hence it should throw a "**not defined**" error. Its accessible only within the scope of the `filter()` function

Comment: Ok. I have modified jquery code. Can you please  help me to correct if I' wrong
    `$(".font-select option").filter(function() {
 
  var current_field = $(this);
 
        return $(current_field).val() == $(".product_addon_option_label").val();
  
    }).attr('selected', true);

    $(".font-select").on("change", function() {
  
  var current_field = $(this);

        $(".product_addon_option_label").val($(current_field).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    });`

Comment: Are you trying to just put the value from select to the closest text input?

Comment: yes. just this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have updated your code a bit. Is this what you are looking for?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Select</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {
var current_field = '';
    $(".font-select option").filter(function() {

        current_field = $(this);

        return $(current_field).val() == $(".product_addon_option_label").val();

    }).attr('selected', true);

    $(".font-select").live("change", function() {
    $(this).prev(".product_addon_option_label").val($(this).val());
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="300">
  <tbody class="ui-sortable" style="">
    <tr class="" style="">
      <td><input class="product_addon_option_label" name="product_addon_option_label" value="Arial" placeholder="Label" type="text">
        <select class="font-select">
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two" selected="selected">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" style="">
      <td><input class="product_addon_option_label" name="product_addon_option_label" value="Thohm" placeholder="Label" type="text">
        <select class="font-select">
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two" selected="selected">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but at strart what does it mean....."var current_field = ". I think you did not put anything afer equal sign

Comment: Yea, my miss. updated the code. Have just initialised with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {    
    $(".font-select").on("change", function() {
      $(this).parent().find('.product_addon_option_label').val($(this).val());
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="300">
  <tbody class="ui-sortable" style="">
    <tr class="" style="">
      <td><input class="product_addon_option_label" name="product_addon_option_label" value="Arial" placeholder="Label" type="text">
        <select class="font-select">
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two" selected="selected">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" style="">
      <td><input class="product_addon_option_label" name="product_addon_option_label" value="Thohm" placeholder="Label" type="text">
        <select class="font-select">
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two" selected="selected">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```